# Allthough not very experienced, I have a great interest in scientific programming. Is Python a good choice compared to MATLAB?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy

I am a grad student in Engineering and I am beginning to realise how important a skill programming is in my profession. In undergrad studies we were introduced to MATLAB (Actually Octave) and I used to think that that was the way to go, but I have been doing some research and it seems that the scientific community is starting to move over to Python, through it's numpy and scipy packages, at an alarming rate.

I feel that I am at the beginning of my 'programming journey' and have been told a few times that I should choose a language and stick to it.

I have basically made up my mind that I want to move over to Python, but would like some informed opinions on my decision?

I am not looking to start a MATLAB vs Python style thread as this will only lead to people giving their opinions as facts and I know this is not the style of this forum. I am simply looking for validation that a move from MATLAB to Python is a good idea for a person in my position.

P.S. I know Python is free and MATLAB is expensive, but that it simply not a good enough reason for me to make this decision.

Comment: What can MATLAB do that Python can't?

Comment: I don't see why you should limit your self with only one language. You could start with only one. python is a good choice.

Comment: Well apparently nothing. But I must say at the moment MATLAB syntax seems allot simpler than that of Python, but then again I keep reading that Python is very simple compared to languages such as C and Fortran, so I will definitely not let that put me off. I am still fairly inexperienced in programming so I'm sure I will pick it up quite quickly, as everyone says it is a fairly easy language to learn.

Comment: If you are starting to learn to program, Python is a very good first language choice. The fact that it can be also used for scientific progamming is a plus. Depending on the field you are in, you may find that many people use MATLAB (or FORTRAN!), and it will be advantageous to learn also them later on. However, as far as scientific coding goes, you will find that the languages are very similar, and much of your knowledge can be reused. Moreover, as Python is a general-purpose language, it will teach you good programming habits better than field-specific niche languages.

Comment: I started in MATLAB and switched to Python, and I am very happy. I know a lot of people who did the same, but I don't know anybody who started in Python and switched to MATLAB. For me Python pluses are 1) Python has normal classes, makes much easier to organize big projects 2) Free, makes it very convenient for Grad Student who needs to switch machines and/or operating systems 3) Open source, can always find what exact implementation is. 4) I prefer Python syntax.

Answer (score 6):

You should consider what particular capabilities you need, and see if Numpy and Scipy can meet them.  Matlab's real value isn't in the base package, which is more-or-less matched by a combination of numpy, scipy and matplotlib, but in the various toolboxes one can purchase.  For instance, I'm not aware of a Robust Control toolbox equivalent for Python.

Another feature of Matlab that doesn't have an easy-to-use Python equivalent is Simulink, especially the mature real-time hardware-in-the-loop simulation and embedded code-generation.  There are open-source projects with similar goals: JModelica is worth looking at, as is Scilab's Scicos.

A final consideration is what is used in the industry you plan to work in.

Having said all that, if you *can* use Python, you should; it's more fun, and it's (probably) a fundamentally better language.  If you do become proficient in Python, switching to Matlab if you have to won't be very difficult.

My experience is that using Python made me a better Matlab programmer; Python's basic facilities (list comprehensions, dictionaries, modules, etc.) made me look for similar capabilities in Matlab, and made me organize my Matlab code better.

Comment: It's interesting that you mention the control system toolbox, as control is one one my greatest interests and core subjects. I have however looked into it and Python-control seems to be a library with most of the features of the control toolbox in MATLAB. See [Python-control](http://python-control.sourceforge.net/manual/intro.html)

Comment: I wasn't aware of Python-control; thanks for the pointer.  I'm not sure it's quite feature compatible: e.g., I don't see model discretization (there might be a Scipy signal processing module that can do that).  It's also not comparable to the robust control toolbox, which has H-infinity synthesis, mu-analysis, etc.

Comment: [Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/dcj6fy/jmodelica_combining_the_power_of_python_and/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) I wrote a small tutorial about JModelica, if it still interests you.

Answer (score 3):

From my experience, using Python is more rewarding, especially for a beginner in enginnering. In comparison to Matlab, Python is a general purpose language, and knowing it makes many more tasks than, say, signal analysis easy to accomplish. In my opinion it's easier to interface with external hardware or to do other tasks where you need a "glue" language.

And with respect to signal processing, numpy, scipy, and matplotlib are a very good choice! I never felt I would miss out on anything! It was rather the other way around that with Matlab I was missing all the general purpose stuff and the "batteries included" nature of Python. The number of freely available libraries for Python is just overwhelming.

On top, basing your work on an open source project pays back. As a student, you can simply install Python on all the machines that matter to you (no additional costs), you can benefit from reading the source of others (great learning experience), and once you are doing some "production" stuff later on, you have the power to fix stuff yourself. With Matlab and other closed-source packages, you always depend on somebody else.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

I personally feel that working with Python is a lot better, As @bdoering mentioned working on Opensource projects is far better than working on closed source.

Matlab is quite industry specific, and is still not wide spread in the industry. If you work with these softwares, sooner or later you will be stuck between different kinds of them too (ex, Matlab vs Mathematica). However, Syntax will be easy to write and modules will run quickly and simulate. But in the end there will always be a limitation with Matlab. My observation says that using using a software like Matlab may provide you quick simulations of graphs and models, but will limit your learning curve.

Go for Python!

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I'm biased toward MATLAB, as that's my background, and I used to work for MathWorks. Python is great too, but I don't know it very well technically, so I won't compare them directly.

Just a couple of thoughts related to assumptions in your question though:

1. Although I'd agree with you that I do see the *scientific* community moving away from MATLAB toward open-source environments such as Python (and others such as R, Scilab, Julia etc), I don't see many commercial engineering companies (aerospace, automotive, electronic engineering etc) doing the same thing. They are mostly pretty committed to MATLAB, and I don't see that changing in the near future. A lot of that is not necessarily because of any advantages of MATLAB itself, though it has many (and some disadvantages, to be sure); a lot of it is because of Simulink, and the Model-Based Design workflow, which have no real alternatives in the open-source world. If, as an engineering student, you're making this decision with regard to your future job prospects, that's one thing to consider.
2. MATLAB really isn't as expensive as you think. Sure, you wouldn't want to buy a commercial license yourself - but you can get [MATLAB Home Edition](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/matlab-home/) for only £85, which doesn't seem that much to me. Commercial companies would obviously prefer a commercial license to be cheaper, but they must get enough value out of MATLAB to justify the cost of a commercial license, otherwise they wouldn't buy it.

Hope that helps!

Comment: True, but what about SME's they can't afford working with Matlab.

Comment: Thank you Sam, it certainly does.

Comment: @ParikshitJoshi Life is tough financially for small companies in all sorts of ways, not just when buying MATLAB. At the end of the day, they need to decide whether MATLAB provides enough value to justify the costs - if it does, then buy it, if it doesn't, then don't.